# All installed modules are missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Last week I installed some modules like PEP257, MYPY, FLAKE8 and Bandit. But then, yesterday, i restarted my PC. Then I want to resume my work. But all the commands are not cognizable.

When I check using

```
python -m pip list
```

it shows just 3 modules :

```
pip        19.1.1 setuptools 40.8.0 virtualenv 16.4.3
```

So, why / how are all the installed modules missing ? What should i do in the future to overcome this.

Iam using Python 3.7 and PIP 19.1.1

thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: always install the modules you need into a specific virtualenv for your project

Comment: Did check your $PYTHONPATH environment variable? Maybe it got changed somehow in your .bashrc

Comment: i guess i know why they are missing. it turns out that i have to be inside virtualenv (?). See the 2 pictures i included. So, why do i have to be inside virtualenv ? whats the deal with it ? i am new to python